# Why does 'man 2 open' say that there are two kinds of open?

Tags: c, linux, overloading, manpage

I ran into this question while typing `man 2 open`. It says that there are two kinds of open, one with two args, and one with three! last time i checked we could not overload functions in C. How did they do this? did they write in C++?

```
int open(const char * pathname, int flags);
int open(const char * pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, they just used variadic function.

```
int open(const char * pathname, int flags, ...);
```

This makes the last argument `mode` optional. The prototypes only show how the function should be used, not the actual interface.

Of course, unlike real overloading, the compiler cannot type-check the `mode` argument, so the user have to be extra careful to ensure only 2 or 3 arguments are passed, and the 3rd argument must be a `mode_t`.

---

BTW, if you check the `man 2 open` for BSD (including OS X) it shows the [correct prototype as above](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/open.2.html).

Comment: If the compiler is aware of POSIX or made aware of the function's argument types via some language extension, it can do the checking. If gcc/glibc aren't already doing that, I wouldn't be surprised to see them add it soon, just like the `printf` argument checks.

Answer (score 10):

For what it's worth, the man page is incorrect. The prototypes it shows:

```
int open(const char * pathname, int flags);
int open(const char * pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

are **not** equivalent to the correct prototype:

```
int open(const char * pathname, int flags, ...);
```

Using the incorrect ones it provides (e.g. if you prototype the function yourself rather than including the right header) will cause your program to have undefined behavior. (And this is not just theoretical; it will probably fail to run on x86_64 and other platforms with pass-by-register ABIs.)

What the man page was trying to express (and doing a very poor job of) is that the variadic part of `open`'s argument list can be either empty or a single `mode_t` type argument, where the absence or presence of the optional argument depends on the value of `flags`.

Answer (score 8):

No, they wrote in C, using varargs.

Check out [stdarg.h](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Stdarg.h), where there are examples.

A variadic function may read as many arguments as it likes from the [ellipsis](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Ellipsis) *(...)* . Any extra arguments the function "does not want" are in fact discarded.